# How is maximum log likelihood calculated for BPSK?

Tags: bpsk, channelcoding, maximum-likelihood-estimation

I am seeking to understand, exactly, how to calculate a soft MLL output from a received BPSK signal, and what information is needed. I would like to implement turbo coding in my system, but the receiver is non-coherent, with a random phase offset and no channel state information available. I would like to know if it is still possible to get good performance from a turbo decoder.

Comment: What do you mean by non-coherent? No carrier and sampling offset recovery at all?

Comment: BPSK cannot be demodulated with a non coherent receiver when the channel has random phase offset; you need to use Differentially-encoded BPSK (DBPSK) and a differentially-coherent receiver.  See [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/62549/235) or [this one](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/53842/235) for some details.

Comment: As Dilip says, there's no information about phase if you're not coherently receiving, so, reception carries literally 0 (mutual) information about transmission, and you cannot make data out of no information. So, it's not clear what you actually want to do here. Are you *sure* you're doing both BPSK and non-coherent reception.